# Very slow file transfer speeds from wired to wireless

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1

I'm trying to transfer files between my Windows 8.1 desktop, which is connected to my network via Gigabit Ethernet, and my Windows 8.1 Surface Pro, which is connected via 802.11n wireless. Although they are able to discover each other on the network, copying files between them is incredibly slow - I get a maximum transfer speed of 350 KB/s.

The Surface has a strong wireless signal and can download files from the Internet at well over 1 MB/s, so it doesn't appear to be a problem with the Surface's wireless networking in general. A slow hard drive isn't the bottleneck, because copying the same file from my desktop to a USB drive proceeds much faster. What could be making Windows file transfers slow on my network, and nothing else?

Some facts about my setup:

- The Surface has a Marvell Avastar 350N wireless adapter with the latest driver installed
- My router is a Netgear WNR3500Lv2, broadcasting 802.11n Wi-Fi on channel 6 with WPA2 encryption
- The desktop has a Realtek Gigabit Ethernet controller embedded on the motherboard (a Gigabyte GA-Z97-HD3)